# Using Casper to log-in a page with Javascript generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to use casper to log-in to http://insider.espn.go.com/insider/pickcenter/. 
Now issue is that when you click log-in button, a AngularJS generated fileds - username and password appear. 
I have put WaitForSelector to wait for this pop-up. But it always exits saying " Timeout expired"

Here's my script. Please help.

```
    var links = [];
var casper = require("casper").create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}
casper.on('page.loaded', function() {
    this.echo('page title is ' + this.getTitle());
});
casper.start('http://insider.espn.go.com/insider/pickcenter/', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.emit('page.loaded');
    casper.capture('test1.png');
    this.click('#ins_signin');

});
casper.wait(5000,function(){
    casper.capture('test2.png')
});
casper.wait(5000,function(){
    casper.capture('test3.png')
});
casper.waitForSelector(".ng-scope", function() {
    this.echo('Login Modal Active!');
    casper.capture('test4.png');
    //this.capture('screenshotofmodal.png', { top: 0, left:0, width:1000, height:  4000}); 

 });

casper.then(function() {
this.fill('input[id="username"]', { q: 'removed' }, true);
    this.fill('input[id="passwordfield"]', { q: 'removed' }, true);

});
casper.then(function() {

    this.click('#submitBtn');
});
casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, before clicking, I would add a check to validate the the button is loaded. After, I would anchor the sign up form on a unique selector. After looking quickly on the page, when you click sign in, the email input has a class "ng-touched" which only appears after clicking on sign up. What I would try would look like this :

```
casper.start('http://insider.espn.go.com/insider/pickcenter/', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.emit('page.loaded');
    casper.capture('test1.png');
});
casper.waitForSelector("#ins_signin",function then(){
    this.click("#ins_signin");
}, function onTimeOut(){
    this.capture('waitSignInFail.png');
}, 5000);

casper.waitForSelector(".ng-touched", function then() {
    this.echo('Login Modal Active!');
    casper.capture('weHaveSignInForm.png');
}, function onTimeOut(){
    this.capture('signInFormFail.png');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I can not comment on your post so I had to answer right away even tho I had questions for you so I will ask them here and hopefully you see it. what does test2.png render for you, with your initial code posted ?